# Cypher: Very slow relationship creation (UNWIND)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the neo4j python API and connecting to a local database. I have a graph which contains 700.000 nodes. I can very quickly create the nodes by using:

```
with session.begin_transaction() as tx: 
    cypher_query = 'UNWIND $batch as row ' \
    'CREATE (n:Node) ' \
    'SET n += row'
    tx.run(cypher_query, batch=batch)
```

The graph presents 4M relationships, and I am trying to create them in the following way:

```
with session.begin_transaction() as tx: 
    cypher_query = 'UNWIND $batch as row ' \
    'MATCH (head:Node) WHERE head.id = row.head_id ' \
    'MATCH (tail:Node) WHERE tail.id = row.tail_id ' \
    'CREATE (head)-[rel:RELATIONSHIP]->(tail) ' \
    'SET rel += row.properties'
    tx.run(cypher_query, batch=batch)
```

The batch size is 10K.
The creation of the relationships is extremely slow. I calculated that it'd take around 30 days. Do you know a work around? Is it normal for it to be so slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution. Execute this query on your database:

`CREATE CONSTRAINT node_id ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE`

It will speed up everything. The idea is the following: if you match node by using the `id`, you must make sure that `id` is unique. If it's not, the time complexity of the query grows a lot.